# Create custom path alias when new user is added in drupal 7

Tags: path-aliases

I've created contents using `custom form`. I don't use content types. I could add, update and delete that content by access `test`, `test/id/edit` and `test/id/delete`.

I've displayed content lists for a user by `tests/uid`. Now I want to use **user name** instead of **uid**. I have to replace space by '-' and also replace all special characters. So my choice is both url alias and path auto.

But I couldn't add custom url pattern into pathauto pattern. There is only available for content types, taxonomy term, user and file path. But I want to custom url pattern for custom content inside the user path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're wanting to implement Pathauto's API. Here's a [tutorial](http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/using-the-pathauto-api-drupal-module-a-simple-example/) on how to do so. Basically, you need to implement [`hook_pathauto()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto/7) and make use of [`pathauto_create_alias()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_create_alias/7) & [`path_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/path_delete/7) when you're performing your Create/Update/Delete operations. It looks like you can use the `token_type` of `user` for your token replacement.

Comment: I need to add path alias for all users and add, update, delete a user

Comment: See the tutorial link for bulk adding/updating. You'll also need to implement user hook functions if you're wanting to take action on path aliases during user creation, updating, & deletion.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working fine. Very nice tutorials.

Comment: Is it possible to use more than one pattern.