# Multiple path alias for a url

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I've installed the [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. I have a content type *article*. When I'm trying to create an article, the path is created automatically in the form **content/article-title**, that is fine.

However, I want to pass some dummy values via url like **content/article-title/value1**, **content/article-title/value2**. So now I have multiple aliases for the url.  I will create some functionality using this dummy value.

If I try to access **node/10/value1**, I can access the page. But I want to access with path alias like **content/article-title/value1**.

How can I access a page using **content/article-title/value1**, **content/article-title/value1** and **content/article-title**?

I don't need to create multiple path alias for url. But I need to access page using above urls.

Is it possible?

**Answer:**

Eventually, I got the solution for this. Please refer http://www.phponwebsites.com/2016/08/drupal-7-pathauto-multiple-url-alias.html

Comment: http://data.agaric.com/multiple-aliases-drupal check this

Answer (score 2):

You need to set path at config >> URL aliases >> patterns under that article patter you need to set something like.

**content/[node:title]/[node:field_machine_name]**

You can access with pattern url otherwise you can access by default with "node/nid".

Comment: It is not based on field. It is a custom value. I need to pass 2 values like value1 and value2

Comment: which kind of value you want to pass?

Comment: String like sum and non-sum

Comment: just enter in tags for sum or non-sum and use that field in content/[node:title]/[node:field_tag]

Comment: Where to do this? and how?

Comment: At config >> URL aliases >> patterns under the article pattern. While you create new article in tags you can set this term.

Comment: How to set 2 values? There is only one textbox for a atricle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29658/discussion-between-vimal-goradiya-and-guru).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider passing the values as parameters instead of arguments.

#### Arguments:

- content/article-title/value1
- content/article-title/value2

#### Parameters:

- content/article-title?key1=[value1]&key2=[value2]

---

Parameters will mean you can still have a single path alias for your node.

You pick up parameters in your code by looking in the global `$_GET` variable.

Comment: Yes we could do this but it affects SEO.

Comment: A great deal of how to handle this is going to depend on what you're doing with it.  How do you plan to add the functionality?  Server-side?  Client-side?

Comment: For client side validation

Comment: You will need mutliple aliases for each node then.  I'm not sure pathauto will do that for you but you should be able to write a custom module that adds new items to the aliases settings (`/admin/config/search/path`) using functions from the pathauto module.

Comment: Yes i need to do. Is any other options like while create node?

Comment: If you want to do it programatically, have a look at [hook_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)

Comment: How to create path alias with custom pattern programmatically?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170356/create-custom-path-alias-when-new-user-is-added-in-drupal-7

Comment: One path can be possible for one node it can't be possible multiple path for one node.

Comment: See other answer - going to delete this one as it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: It is the correct solution. But i have to add 2 custom pattern for a content type. If i used hook_pathauto(), i could to use only one pattern

Answer (score 0):

You will need multiple aliases for the same node.

Create a custom module that uses [hook_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) to trigger a function that uses [path_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/path_save/7) to add a new alias for the node.

path_save only overwrites paths if you direct it to do so with `$path['pid']`;